# YOLO v8 : WARNING ⚠️ no model scale passed. Assuming scale='n'

Tags: yolo, yolov8

Getting the following warning while training custom dataset :
"WARNING ⚠️ no model scale passed. Assuming scale='n'."

I don't see any scale argument. Following is the training arguments

CLI: yolo detect train data=visionDemo.yaml model=YOLOv8x.yaml epochs=600 imgsz=640 device=mps optimizer=Adam project=visionDemo name=vdYolov8x

Thanks

My system is Macbook, Ventura 13.4.2. Apple silicon M2.